# На Binance какой отправлять параметр в side в режиме хеджирования?

Tags: binance

Binance, создание нового ордера, использую режим хеджирования Hedge Mode

Если кто сталкивался с таким, подскажите какой правильно отправлять параметр в `side` при открытии лонга или шорта ?

При открытии лонга `positionSide: LONG, side: ?`

При открытии шорта `positionSide: SHORT, side: ?`

```
POST /fapi/v1/order (HMAC SHA256)

side // BUY or SELL
positionSide // Default BOTH for One-way Mode ; LONG or SHORT for Hedge Mode
```

В официальной документации не нашел такой информации

Answer (score 0):

**Режим `Hedge Mode`**

Открытие `LONG` ордера

```
side = "BUY",
positionSide = "LONG",
```

Открытие `SHORT` ордера

```
side = "SELL",
positionSide = "SHORT",
```

Закрытие `LONG` ордера

```
side = "SELL",
positionSide = "LONG",
```

Закрытие `SHORT` ордера

```
side = "BUY",
positionSide = "SHORT",
```